# The method setCurrentMinute(Integer) in the type TimePicker is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, timepicker

Anyone have an idea why I might be getting this error?

All I'm trying to do is save the hour selected by the timepicker... I'm sure it's something simple I've overlooked.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Amani Swann

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

 private long rowID; 
 private EditText nameEt;
 private EditText capEt;
 private EditText codeEt;
 private TimePicker timeEt;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

      nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
      capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
      codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
      timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);


      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

      if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
         capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
         codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
         timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getString("time"));  
      }

      Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
             if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
             {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                   new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                   {
                      @Override
                      protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                      {
                         saveContact();
                         return null;
                      }

                      @Override
                      protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                      {
                         finish();
                      }
                   }; 

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
             }

             else
             {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                alert.show();
             }
          } 
     });
   }

   private void saveContact() 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

      if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
      {
          dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                  capEt.getText().toString(),
                  timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                  codeEt.getText().toString());
      }
      else
      {
         dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
            nameEt.getText().toString(),
            capEt.getText().toString(),
            timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
            codeEt.getText().toString());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the message clear? You can't pass a String to setCurrentMinute(), because it takes an int as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `setCurrentHour()` expects an Integer, but by calling `getString()` you are passing a String and, as the error states, there is no method for `setCurrentHour(String)`.

You don't tell us where the Intent's extras are set, so this solution is a guess. But try:

```
timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getInt("time"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the extras object does not have a `getInt()` method, try something like: `timeEt.setCurrentHour(Integer.valueof(extras.getString("time")));`

Comment: Bundle has [`getInt()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29). While you could convert the Integer to a String then back to an Integer, I prefer skipping the circular data type casting.